# Архивация в коде Objective-C с помощью терминала

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Обычные консольные приложения в Cocoa легко запускаются при помощи NSTask.
Пишу метод по архивации файлов. Выдает:

> ERROR---Archieve don't writing

Вроде все верно. Почему не создает zip архив? Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Не могу нигде найти русскоязычного объяснения методов NSTask.

```
- (NSString *)zip:(NSString *)source to:(NSString *)target {
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",target,source]]) {
        NSString *sourceWithoutExtension=source;
        NSRange extensionInSource=[source rangeOfString:@"."];
        if (extensionInSource.length==0) {
            sourceWithoutExtension=[source substringToIndex:extensionInSource.location];
        }
        NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/zip"];
        [task setArguments:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",target,sourceWithoutExtension],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",target,source]]];
        [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
        [task launch];
        [task waitUntilExit];
        NSLog(@"Archiving complete!");

        NSString *zipPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.zip",target,sourceWithoutExtension];
        NSError *error2;
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:zipPath]) {
            NSLog(@"Archiving complete!!!!!!!!!!");
            return zipPath;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR---Archieve don't writing");
            return [error2 localizedDescription];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR---FILE NOT EXIST");
        return [error localizedDescription];
    }
}
```

Comment: Логи добавлял для собственной проверки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, кому- нибудь пригодится:

```
-(NSString*)zip:(NSString*)target {
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error=nil;
NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe *outputPipe=[NSPipe pipe];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:target]) {
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/zip"];
    [task setArguments:@[[target stringByDeletingPathExtension],target]];
    [task setStandardOutput:outputPipe];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[target stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"]]) {
        return [[target stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];
    } else {
        return [error localizedDescription];
    }
} else {
    return [error localizedDescription];
}
```

}

Намудрил с путями, как результат- неправильная работа программы. К тому же, стоило пересмотреть определение метода т. к. в исходной задаче требовалось создать архив в ТОЙ ЖЕ директории, что и исходный файл.